# Loading a cookie in google app engine

Tags: python, facebook, google-app-engine, cookies, dictionary

What's the best way to load a facebook cookie in google app engine (python)?

The cookies attribute (in the request class) is a dictionary of cookies. Once I get mine I have a string with & sign separating the attributes. How can I turn this easily into a dictionary?

This is the string: `"access_token=value&expires=value&secret=value&session_key=value&sig=value&uid=value"`

(I've tried json.loads but it didn't work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[cgi.parse_qs](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html#cgi.parse_qs)